# Completely restricting all types of access to a folder

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, bsd

I am making a cocoa application, which creates some folders at my specified location in the user's environment. Now i want to protect these folders from any type of read, write, copy, drag access from all type of users(i.e Not accessible for admin and non-admin users).Is there a way to protect these folders from any type of access.
Can we use, NSFileManager method **-setAttributes:OfItemAtPath:error:**
But i am not sure on attributes dictionary of this method.

Basically i want to provide trail of some files to the user (let's say 1 day trial), and removing those files as soon as the trail expires, and all those files are placed inside a certain folder in the user's environment. What should be the best approach i should use to protect those files?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NSFileManager setAttributes:OfItemAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:) with the attributes key [NSFilePosixPermissions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSFilePosixPermissions). With this, you can set the [Unix file permissions](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/FilePermissions.htm) of your folder by specifying them with an integer value that represents the permission bit pattern. Setting it to zero would mean no access at all to that directory:

```
NSDictionary *attribs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    NSFilePosixPermissions, [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
```

However, it would still be possible to move or rename that directory.

Comment: Can we create a user on user's machine and make that user owner of that folder and giving all modify rights only to that user.

Comment: Nothing you can do ACL-wise will prevent admins or the owner from resetting the permissions and accessing the files.

Comment: @Andrew Medico Can i do something, when someone tries to copy,drag my folder from any location. Then i want to restrict copy,drag operations.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: No.** Someone with elevated privileges can do just about anything. No playing with permissions will get you there and still allow your application to access the files.

*If you could just turn off all access rights how would you expect your own application to access the files? Turning on the access rights is itself an access right...*

**Longer answer: Maybe.** This depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you really want to stop the files being copied, or just their contents accessed?

Encryption can be used to protect content (e.g. at the file level, using an encrypted sparsebundle image, etc.), storing identification information in a file can alert you that you’re using a copy (e.g. see what happens if you move/copy a VMWare virtual machine or recreate a Google Drive folder), etc.

And you can always implement your own filesystem using FUSE; and prevent copying, access, etc. by your own mechanism, however the filesystem as a whole could still be copied (i.e. effectively implement your own equivalent of an encrypted sparsebundle via FUSE and implement your own access mechanism).

*What are you trying to achieve? If you spell that out folk might be able to suggest alternative solutions.*

See also [this question on preventing root from writing to files](https://superuser.com/questions/104015/removing-write-permission-does-not-prevent-root-from-writing-to-the-file).

Comment: Basically i want to provide trail of some files to the user (let's say 1 day trial), and removing those files as soon as the trail expires, and all those files are placed inside a certain folder in the user's environment. What should be the best approach i should use to protect those files?

Comment: @johnfedric - Add that information as an edit to your question, others may not see it here. What is best will depend on what is in those files, how usable they are outside of your app, whether they really need to exist as files in the filesystem, etc., etc. As mentioned above one option is encryption - 2-key encryption where your server encrypts with one key, your app decrypts with another, and in addition to whatever data is in the file there is also metadata giving its expiry date etc. Whether that is best or even suits for your scenario you'll have to decide.