# OSX- Auto Delete file after x-time

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

Can we add metadata to unlink/remove a file after x-time automatically. That is system automatically removes that file, if it finds that particular metadata attached with that file

**Note**- file can be present at any location, and user may move that file anywhere on their system, but based on that metadata file should get deleted(i.e system should call unlink/remove) for that file.

Is there a cocoa/objective-c/c++ api to set such metadata/attributes of a file?

The main point is i am creating an application through which i am providing some trial files to the user, and those files are also usable by other application which recognises them. After trial expiry, i want to delete those files, but user can always move my files to a different location and use them forever, how to protect those files from permanent use?

Comment: While I've given an answer, it does sound like you're asking the wrong question - are you trying to create a cache of some type?

Comment: @Petesh The main point is i am creating an application through which i am providing some trial files to the user, and those files are also usable by other application which recognises them. After trial expiry, i want to delete those files, but user can always move my files to a different location and use them forever, how to protect those files from permanent use?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in mechanism to auto-delete a file based on some metadata.

You could add the feature yourself, with an accompanying agent that would trawl for files with the metadata and delete them when the time came.

Comment: You could add the feature yourself,with an accompanying agent that would trawl for files with the metadata and delete them when the time came. I think creating an application for this must be launched by system so anyone user using the system may stop that application?

Comment: The main point is i am creating an application through which i am providing some trial files to the user, and those files are also usable by other application which recognises them. After trial expiry, i want to delete those files, but user can always move my files to a different location and use them forever, how to protect those files from permanent use?

Comment: Now that I understand your reasoning, I would suggest accepting that the files will not be deleted and start from that point. There are far too many ways of getting the files into a state where they can't be deleted even **if** you could track them. If I put the file on a windows server, would you expect the windows server to respect the 'delete me' flag and erase the file?

Comment: After trial expiry when user launches the application, you can do the metadata search in system using NSMetaDataQuery for finding those files and you can remove.

Comment: @SheenVempeny That won't find files in `.zip` files, time machine archives, etc. If there is other software which can read the files, what happens if that software copies the data out - you can't attach metadata to that as it's not created in your application. I'm suggesting that the OP try a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for good housekeeping you can follow @Petesh answer.

If you are doing this because you really want those files gone then no. The user could move the file to a USB stick and remove it, or edit the metadata, etc.

Your earlier question ["Completely restricting all types of access to a folder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008635/completely-restricting-all-types-of-access-to-a-folder) seems to addressing the same issue and the suggestions are the same as given there - use encryption or implement your own file system.

E.g. have a special "trial file" format which is the same as the ordinary format - which is readable by other apps - but encrypted and includes an expiry date. Your app then decrypts the file, checks the date, and either does its thing or reports to the user the file is out of date.

The system isn't unbreakable, but its a reasonable barrier - easy for you to do, too hard for the average user to break.

Comment: Have a special "trial file" format which is the same as the ordinary format - which is readable by other apps - but encrypted and includes an expiry date, How other apps using my files would be able to decrypt that?

Comment: I may have misunderstood, I assumed the usability of the trial file by apps other than yours was not a concern.